# Error crawling a scrapy spider: twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following spider which I'm pretty sure was working before:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from Funda.items import FundaItem

class FundaSpider(CrawlSpider):

    # def __init__(self, url='http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam'):
    #     self.start_urls = [url]

    name = "Funda"
    allowed_domains = ["funda.nl"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/"]

    le1 = LinkExtractor(allow=r'%s+huis-\d{8}' % start_urls[0])

    le2 = LinkExtractor(allow=r'%s+p\d+' % start_urls[0])   # Page number links such as http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/p10/

    rules = (
    Rule(le1, callback='parse_item'),
    Rule(le2, callback='get_max_page_number')
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        links = self.le1.extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            if link.url.count('/') == 6 and link.url.endswith('/'):
                item = FundaItem()
                item['url'] = link.url
                yield item

    def get_max_page_number(self, response):
        links = self.le2.extract_links(response)
        max_page_number = 0
        for link in links:
            if link.url.count('/') == 6 and link.url.endswith('/'):
                page_number = int(link.url.split("/")[-2].strip('p'))
                if page_number > max_page_number:
                    max_page_number = page_number
        return max_page_number
```

where `items.py` is

```
import scrapy

class FundaItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    text = scrapy.Field()
```

If I try to run it using `scrapy crawl Funda`, I get an error message which ends with

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1173, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 684, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

I have also been running another spider from a script using `CrawlerProcess` from `scrapy.crawler`, and suspect that this might be interfering with this spider. How can I make the spider run?